# Godot 4.0 3D - When changing the camera node tree position that is inside a viewport it does not render the background

Tags: godot, godot4

Context: I am making a first person shooter and I am trying to make the weapon only render in one camera so that I can avoid the weapon clipping through walls.

Issue: I have setup two cameras 1 called main cam that renders everything but the gun, and another camera called weapon cam that only renders the gun, now if I don't do anything to the weapon cam it renders the gun but does not follow the player only being able to see the gun if I move in front of the weapon cam.

Attempts of fixing the issue:
Attempt 1:
I have tried setting the position and rotation of the weapon cam to be the same as the players.x rotation and cameras.y rotation it kinda works but it requires a process to always update the values which I think is not good.

Attempt 2: I think this is the better option, so I changed the weapon cams node position in the tree to be under the main camera position this means it will follow exactly the main camera and it works apart from it stops rendering the whole background/environment.

code:

Player_script

```
func _ready():
    weapon_cam.get_parent().remove_child(weapon_cam)
    main_cam.add_child(weapon_cam)
```

Here is the node scene, as you can currently see I have the camera seperated for now and I change the node position in the code.

[image: Scene layout]

as you can see the game is only rendering the weapon a block currently.

[image: In game]

and this is the scene that should also be rendered
[image: Main scene]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9i6uxm_ioG0 uses a script to update the position of the gun camera. There's no shame in that, but you can do it with a `RemoteTransform3D` node as well.

Comment: Updating the camera transform every frame is fine, not a big deal.

Comment: thanks for you guys input, I have decided to simply set its transform, Honestly wanted the moving around the child node to work but it causes such a weird issue of not rendering the background, I'm more surprised there isn't a 3d viewport that allows to follow the child nodes.